# Delete data from Firebase realtime database where time is X

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just wanted to delete data from Firebase realtime database where data is older than 1 hour.
Is there any query for the Firebase query or not for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Database doesn't have a "delete where" type of query.  You will have to break this down into three main steps:

1. Query for all the data to delete, using a timestamp as a filter
2. Iterate the results
3. Delete each child

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: These tasks should all be straightforward to perform if you've reviewed the documentation for Realtime Database.  It doesn't get much easier.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write